# How to resolve unable to find device with the name: "Nexus 4 (Lollipop)" in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have been battling with xamarine ide for a while now, I was unble to deploy my app to the emulator. Although I am a  novice to xamarine IDE. The version am using is Xamarine Studio 6.3

pls I want someone to guide me here maybe I am missing something that did not allowed me to build an android app on Xamarine Studion Ide 6.3

These are the things I installed on my system to get started:
1. Xamarine Studio 6.3
2. Oracle vm virtual box  (version 5.0.4)
3. Xamarine android player  (XAP 0.6.5)
4. JDK 8
5. JTK for .NET (version 2.12.38)

Pls I really need your help if there is anything to install again so that I can get Xamarine IDE perfect for use to build an android app. Also if all what I have installed above are irrelevant, pls I need all the proper step here to get started. Thanks for your response.

Comment: This may help, not my realm [Devices not showing up](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10937/devices-not-showing-up-in-android-target-device-dropdown)

Comment: Or try this: https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Xamarin Android Player has been deprecated

Comment: Thanks for your response  JimBobBennett . which one do you recommended

Answer (score 0):

Any device/emulator that is connected to your local instance of `adb` will show up in the `Android Device List`. If you are looking for a specific emulator such as `Nexus 4(Lollipop)`, this was most likely provided in `Xamarin Android Player` or `Visual Studio Emulator For Android`. Both of these are now officially deprecated and removed from the default device list **unless** they are already running. Beforehand, they were added as **default** emulators that you could run straight from the `Android Device List`.

You can still run the emulators with their standalone programs to boot the emulators and they should appear on your device list as long as you can see them with the `adb devices` command.

Comment: what do you mean by standalone programs. I am a novice, kindly explain where to get the standalone programs to boot the emulators. The error i am seen is Unable to find the device with the name Nexus 4 Lollipop. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please see: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/ for recommendations